# Hiding part of R code in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How do I omit parts of a chunk in Rmarkdown?

For instance:

````
```{r echo T, eval = T}
df <- readRDS("yourfile.RDS")
df <- readRDS("secretfile.RDS") ### NEED TO OMIT THIS PART ONLY
df
```
````

I am aware of the `include = F`, or `echo = F` options but that would either omit the output of `df` or omit the code entirely.

Alternatively, I could do:

````
```{r echo T, eval = F}
df <- readRDS("yourfile.RDS")
```
```{r echo = F, eval = T}
df <- readRDS("secretfile.RDS") ### NEED TO OMIT THIS PART ONLY
```
```{r eval = T, echo = T}
df
```
````

But that is a clunky way to do it and it chops the code blocks. The output should look like:

```
df <- readRDS("yourfile.RDS")
df
```

With the output of `df` following.

Thanks!

Edit: `"yourfile.RDS"` is a placeholder for demonstration purposes in my document. Therefore, the line of code `df <- readRDS("yourfile.RDS")` cannot be evaluated.

Comment: If you aren't evaluating the code with "yourfile.RDS", why not put the secret, evaluated code at the top? That way you don't mess up your formatting.

Comment: Hi, I need to omit `readRDS("secretfile.RDS")`. It has some parameters that should not be displayed on a document for privacy reasons. The idea is to show how to do this process with the same name `df` for the data. That's why I can't even read the file before (` ```{r include = F} df <- readRDS("secretfile.RDS")``` `.

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is that you can hide the code, but put it above the unevaluated code block. Then after the unevaluated code block (that is displayed), you can create another evaluated but hidden code block that returns your df.

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Comment: Glad to help, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the code, but put it above the unevaluated code block. Then after the unevaluated code block (that is displayed), you can create another evaluated but hidden code block that returns your df.

For example:

````
```{r echo = F, eval = T}
df <- readRDS("secretfile.RDS") ### NEED TO OMIT THIS PART ONLY
```
```{r echo = T, eval = F}
df <- readRDS("yourfile.RDS")
df
```
```{r echo = F, eval = T}
df
```
````

OP here. Thanks @be_green! Just a slight improvement to your code above:

````
```{r echo = T, eval = F}
df <- readRDS("yourfile.RDS")
df
```
```{r echo = F, eval = T}
df <- readRDS("secretfile.RDS") ### NEED TO OMIT THIS PART ONLY
df
```
````

Answer (score 8):

The `echo` parameter can take numbers, not just `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  They are treated as indices into the vector of expressions in the chunk.

So to hide the second line of code, use `echo = -2`.

The `eval` parameter also accepts indices, but it will display things with comment markers if you set them not to be eval'd, so you can't (easily?) display line 1 but execute line 2.  You can do this:

````
```{r eval=-1, echo=-2}
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
```
````

and line 1 won't be executed.  The chunk will be displayed as

```
## a <- 1
c <- 3
```

Comment: Thanks @user2554330. I didn't know about the indices for the `echo` and `eval` parameters. I can't apply your solution, however, because `"yourfile.RDS"` does not exist which would throw an error but I wasn't clear in my question so I'll check your comment too. Cheers

Comment: In that case, displaying it with comment markers might be appropriate.